# Slideshow with JavaScript

Tags: switch-statement, case

I want to create a **slideshow**. Each time one of the three **dots/buttons is pressed a different set of three images shows.**I can't get my mind around it and I got so tangled that I need your help.

Here is my code. I take any suggestions. The problem lies somewhere in the function.

I take suggestions/corrected errors/anything! :) :) :)

```js
function currentSlide(img) {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImages1');
  switch (image) {
    case 1:
      image = document.getElementById('myImages1'); //First set of images
    case 2:
      image = document.getElementById('myImages2'); //second set of images
    case 3:
      image = document.getElementById('myImages3'); //third set of images

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>h</title>



</head>

<body>
  <h1>h</h1>

  <div id="myImages1">
    <!--  First set of images -->
    <img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8450/8026519634_f33f3724ea_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7218/7209301894_c99d3a33c2_h.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7231/6947093326_df216540ff_b.jpg ">
  </div>

  <div id="myImages2">
    <!--    Second set of images -->
    <img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8788/17367410309_78abb9e5b6_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5814/20700286354_762c19bd3b_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5647/21137202535_404bf25729_b.jpg ">
  </div>
  <div id="myImages3">
    <!--      Third set of images-->
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5588/14991687545_5c8e1a2e86_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3888/14878097108_5997041006_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7579/15482110477_0b0e9e5421_b.jpg">

  </div>
  <!-- The dots/circles/buttons -->
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <!--Each of the dot calls a case in the switch statement ( 1, 2 or 3)-->
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**FOR BLANCO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My black and white slideshow</title>


  <style>
    /*The style of the images*/
    
    img {
      width: 30%;
      float: left;
      margin: 1.66%;
      /*3x30 + 6x1.66 = 99.96%*/
    }
    /*The style of the title*/
    
    h1 {
      margin-left: 1.66%;
      font-size: 23px;
      font-weight: 800;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
      width: 30%;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    /*The style of the dots/buttons*/
    
    .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    /*Dots apear darker when hovered over*/
    
    .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }
    
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>My black and white slideshow</h1>

  <div id="myImages1">
    <!--  First set of images -->
    <img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8450/8026519634_f33f3724ea_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7218/7209301894_c99d3a33c2_h.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7231/6947093326_df216540ff_b.jpg ">
  </div>

  <div id="myImages2" class="hide">
    <!--    Second set of images -->
    <img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8788/17367410309_78abb9e5b6_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5814/20700286354_762c19bd3b_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5647/21137202535_404bf25729_b.jpg ">
  </div>
  <div id="myImages3" class="hide">
    <!--      Third set of images-->
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5588/14991687545_5c8e1a2e86_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3888/14878097108_5997041006_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7579/15482110477_0b0e9e5421_b.jpg">

  </div>
  <!-- The dots/circles/buttons -->
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <!--Each of the dot calls a case in the switch statement ( 1, 2 or 3)-->
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
  <script>
    var image = document.getElementById('myImages1');
    function currentSlide(img) {
      image.classList.add('hide');
      switch (img) {
        case 1: //First set of images
          image = document.getElementById('myImages1');
          break;
        case 2: //second set of images
          image = document.getElementById('myImages2');
          break;
        case 3: //third set of images
          image = document.getElementById('myImages3');
          break;
      }
      image.classList.remove('hide');
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the following line for: `var image = documents.getElementById('myImages1');` ? It *masks* the value you pass to the function.

Comment: Initializing the variable with which the switch statement should work..I guess. It is one of my first "big"projects with JS and I am obviously doing something wrong. Should I delete this line?

Comment: It is **your** code. Why are you *guessing*?

Comment: ``documents`` is wrong DOM. use ``document``

Comment: Sorry. I am still struggling with functions in JS and how everything should work in them. I want to give it an initial value of the first set of images.

Comment: Thank you Gerardo BLANCO! I edited that typo. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: PM 77-1 - I left it only like that: var image; But the function still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few mistakes on your part:

1. use `document.getElem....` to target at any object in the DOM, not `documents.`
2. In a switch, when you end a case you want to put `break;` so it doesnt do every case on your switch.

Hope this helps. Will be on stand by if needed :)

```js
var image = document.getElementById('myImages1');

function currentSlide(img) {
  image.classList.add('hide');
  switch (img) {
    case 1: //First set of images
      image = document.getElementById('myImages1');
      break;
    case 2: //second set of images
      image = document.getElementById('myImages2');
      break;
    case 3: //third set of images
      image = document.getElementById('myImages3');
      break;
  }
  image.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

```css
/*The style of the images*/

img {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  /*3x30 + 6x1.66 = 99.96%*/
}


/*The style of the title*/

h1 {
  margin-left: 1.66%;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


/*The style of the dots/buttons*/

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*Dots apear darker when hovered over*/

.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My black and white slideshow</title>



</head>

<body>
  <h1>My black and white slideshow</h1>

  <div id="myImages1">
    <!--  First set of images -->
    <img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8450/8026519634_f33f3724ea_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7218/7209301894_c99d3a33c2_h.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7231/6947093326_df216540ff_b.jpg ">
  </div>

  <div id="myImages2" class="hide">
    <!--    Second set of images -->
    <img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8788/17367410309_78abb9e5b6_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5814/20700286354_762c19bd3b_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5647/21137202535_404bf25729_b.jpg ">
  </div>
  <div id="myImages3" class="hide">
    <!--      Third set of images-->
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5588/14991687545_5c8e1a2e86_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3888/14878097108_5997041006_b.jpg ">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7579/15482110477_0b0e9e5421_b.jpg">

  </div>
  <!-- The dots/circles/buttons -->
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <!--Each of the dot calls a case in the switch statement ( 1, 2 or 3)-->
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I changed the code according to you but it still doesn't work. I think I am having trouble with that 'classList'. How do I use this exactly? Console in Chrome dives this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Comment: @EnthusiasmforC classList let u add/remove/toggle the classes of your code

Comment: @EnthusiasmforC check the html i uploaded. I added classes to you myImages2 and 3

Comment: @EnthusiasmforC also check my css. I created the hidden styles

Comment: @EnthusiasmforC if you are doing ``image.classList`` it means that image is null. How are you targeting that objet

Comment: Yes. I have done those changes. ...What am I missing?

Comment: @EnthusiasmforC i would love seeing your code for a faster debbuging

Comment: I put the new code under the old one in the question. Can you see it that way?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @EnthusiasmforC The problem was with where you putted the sript. It was on the ``head`` os the document, so it was loading before the html had loaded. You should putted before ``body`` ends

Comment: @EnthusiasmforC we got it now?

Comment: YES! Thank you very much Blanco! You are the best! I will take into account everything you showed and I will learn more! Thank you!

Comment: @EnthusiasmforC you are welcome. Please dont forget upvotting and asigning the answer if it solved your question. Have a good one and code on!

Answer (score 0):

`image` will not be 1, 2 or 3, it is an object. You could rather use a separate state variable for tracking where you are. And take a `break` at the end of the `case`s.

```js
var phase=1;

function doSomething(){
    var image=document.getElementById("image");
    switch(phase){
        case 1:
            phase=2;
            image.innerHTML="First image";
            break;
        case 2:
            phase=3;
            image.innerHTML="Second image";
            break;
        case 3:
            phase=1;
            image.innerHTML="Third image";
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doSomething()">Clicky</button>
<div id="image"></div>
```

Then, for your particular use you could play with styles, `display` in particular, and probably without `switch-case`:

```js
var phase=1;

function doSomething(){
    var groups=document.getElementsByClassName("groups");
    for(var i=0;i<groups.length;i++){
        var group=groups[i];
        if(group.id==="group"+phase){
            group.style.display="block";
        } else {
            group.style.display="none";
        }
    }
    phase++;
    if(phase>3)phase=1;
}
```

```css
.groups{display:none}
```

```html
<button onclick="doSomething()">Clicky</button>
<div class="groups" id="group1">Some images</div>
<div class="groups" id="group2">Some other images</div>
<div class="groups" id="group3">Yet another group of images</div>
```